# Broken images displaying image from database

Tags: php, html, database, blob

Hello i am trying to retrieve image stored in database as BLOB however it is coming back as broken so the image doesnt display what am i doing wrong code below.

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
$query = "SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY item_id DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['photo'] ).'" height="100" width="100" class="img-thumnail" />';
    echo '</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>';  
}  
?>
```

Comment: You mean base64_decode right?

Comment: @Forbs No, encode is correct, it's for an inline image.

Comment: Looks ok at first glance. I don't know offhand if `image/jpeg` for the MIME type is wrong but I know that `image/jpg` works in similar code I have.

Comment: Other than that, make sure you're getting non-empty data back in `$row['photo']` and make sure that the originally encoded image was a JPEG. (I.e., versus a PNG or something.)

Comment: Hello it is recognising that i have 4 images as 4 blocks are displayed however all 4 are broken the images are stored as blob in the database and yes they are all jpg

Comment: And the HTML output of the script looks as expected?

Comment: yes i am running this on a new document with only this php code which is shown above i am simply testing how to retrieve the image from the daatabase alhough it recognises there is 4 records all 4 are broken

Comment: Can you post a exemple of the content of $row['photo'] ?

Comment: sorry how do you do that that is my entire code which i have above sorry im a noob at php so some guidance is needed

Answer (score 0):

Use [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function while save BLOB image into database. Because apostrophe `'` may broken your image, addslashes function replace `'` with `\'` which solve the problem.

**For Inserting BLOB image into DataBase**

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']));
$query = "INSERT INTO item (item_id,photo) VALUES('','$image')";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

**For Accessing BLOB image From DB**

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
$query = "SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY item_id DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['photo'] ).'" height="100" width="100" class="img-thumnail" />';
    echo '</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>';  
}
```

Comment: for the inserting blob in to data base i am getting an error line 2 'images' is undefined index how do i fix this

Comment: Here `images` will be the name of your uploaded file name in the form ie. `<input type="file" name="img">` here `$_FILES['images']['tmp_name']` will be `$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']`

Comment: <p>Photo: <input type="file" name="images"/>*</p>  this is my form still an error

Comment: After post your form use this code to see file content `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES);`